# Lost command block!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was tinkering with a new command configuration, and I placed a repeating command block underground that gives me superspeed.  I forgot to take it's coordinates, and I left. I was testing range, and I found it NEVER. WEARS. OFF. I can't find it anymore, and I can't turn it off!! I'm in a superflat world, so I can't really remember the place from surroundings. And now I'm stuck with level 15 speed effect.

Is there a /testforblock command that will look in a large radius, not just one block?

Comment: I know, my point is I'd preferably like to have this ordeal over with quickly. This practically makes it debilitating to play. This is one of my favorite worlds, but now playing it makes me nauseous. I'll edit the title, but my point still stands.

Comment: Thank you, MBraedley. I didn't know someone had already asked that question. I guess this is a very common problem...

Comment: Well, at least 6 others have asked similar questions, so yeah, it's a common problem.  Just be sure to do a search first when you come back to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Go download NBTExplorer.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac)

Open it.  Click on the world name you want to search. (In my case BigRed)
[image: Window]

Click search menu, click Find.

Check the Name check box and type `Command` in the search field and click Find.
[image: Find]

It will find any command blocks.  If it finds the wrong one, you can use Find Next menu.

Once it locates your block, you will see this:
[image]

You can see the command and the coordinates.  You can actually double click the Command portion and set the command value to nothing from NBTExplorer.  If you do, make sure you are not playing that world at the same time.  Also remember to click File -> Save before trying to play the world.

Comment: That sounds awesome! I small problem, though: do you have to pay for it? I don't download a lot of add-ons or mods I have to pay for. I will look into it, though. I would check off answered, but I'm not sure it works for me yet. If it does, I'll check it!

Comment: It is free.  It is an external program like mcedit, it is not a mod.

Comment: Also, just to note, if you are going to 'tinker', create a new world to do that in.  In my case, BigRed is a custom created, sandstone lined, creative world, with cheats.  It is littered with all kinds of strange experiments I have done over time.  Don't tinker in a world you care about.  New worlds are free.  Wrecking one you care about would be a bummer.

Answer (score -1):

MCEdit can show you where tile entities (such as command blocks) are, even through blocks. You could look around underground for your command block and delete it using MCEdit.

Comment: That sounds good, and that was a thought of mine. But here's the issue: I don't have MCEdit, and while I wish I did, it costs money, and my parents won't let me.

Comment: MCEdit is a free program. Wherever you are looking and seeing a price is a scam. http://mcedit.net

Comment: Wait... MCEdit is free?!?! I'VE BEEN LIED TO!!!